# How do I set up an online repository using TortoiseSVN (Windows)?

Tags: windows, svn, repository, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to set up a repository that is accessible to other members of my project over the internet using TortoiseSVN.

Right now, we're working with the mindset that we might want to sell the finished product eventually, which means whatever we use needs to be free for commercial use.

I was hoping someone on here would be kind enough to either provide a step-by-step or point me to one that would explain what I need to do to create a repository that can be accessed over the internet.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

TortoiseSVN is a Subversion client; you need a server to make your repositories accessible remotely. While you can use Subversion locally without any server, if you want to make your repositories available to other team members remotely then you have to deploy a Subversion server or use some online Subversion hosting service.

Therefore, there are numerous options:

- Install Subversion server on your LAN and open it to the Internet,
- Install Subversion server on some cloud platform such as Microsoft Azure or Amazon AWS. For example, here is an instruction on installing VisualSVN Server on Azure: https://mictorino.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/windowsazure_visualsvnquickstart.pdf.
- Use hosted Subversion, such as SlikSVN, Assembla, Beanstalk, Unfuddle, whatever. There are a lot such services.

Answer (score 0):

These guys will give you free svn hosting and there are instructions on how to set up your repo.

https://helpdesk.assembla.com/customer/portal/articles/1604338-subversion-svn-getting-started-guide

After your repo is created and configured adding it to your svn client should be easy.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I was under the impression Assembla was for open-source projects? Also, from my knowledge, there's a limit to how much can be stored in the repository (I believe it limits you to something like 1GB), which won't work for this.

I need a private repository that our group can use without any commercial strings attached to it, which is why I was wanting to use TortoiseSVN.

Comment: that may well be true. Tortoise is just an svn client. You will need an svn host.  BTW 1GB is quite large for a repository but it happens. Maybe play around with svn locally to get a handle on how it works with tortoise. What languages, platforms etc are you targeting? SVN has largely been replaced by git and mercurial at this point so I am curious why you chose it.

Comment: @errata svn hasn't been replaced neither by git nor by mercurial.

Comment: I said largely. http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=git%2C%20svn%2C%20mercurial&cmpt=q&tz=

Comment: @errata this is not a representative study. Just a hype that results into huge search volume.